# Does boto3 v1.9.244 support creating an 's3' resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.6, boto3

I am attempting to retrieve a list of files from S3 with a specific prefix using an AWS Lambda. I bundle the Lambda with `boto3-1.9.244` (the latest version). When I run the Lambda, I receive a `SyntaxError` on the S3 resource assignment although it could have something to do with Boto3 session.

I'm using `Python 3.6` and AWS Lambda uses `boto3-1.9.221` and `botocore-1.12.221`. When I run the code without bundling the latest version of boto3, it works. My current solution is to simply bundle `boto3-1.9.221` with the lambda code rather than the latest version of boto3.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

I expect it to create an s3 resource, but I get this error:

```
invalid syntax (_base.py, line 414): SyntaxError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_handler
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  File "/var/task/boto3/__init__.py", line 100, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/var/task/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/var/task/botocore/session.py", line 839, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 80, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 110, in _create_client_class
    base_classes=bases)
  File "/var/task/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/task/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/var/task/boto3/utils.py", line 61, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/var/task/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/task/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 15, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import create_transfer_manager
  File "/var/task/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 127, in <module>
    from s3transfer.exceptions import RetriesExceededError as \
  File "/var/task/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/var/task/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/var/task/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 414
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. Can you please show us more of your code (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that we can try to reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support. So this issue is not related to the API version.

You can access a specific API version just by replacing ***latest*** with the version number you want in the URL.

***Latest***

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket

***1.9.244***

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.244/reference/services/s3.html#bucket

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I was installing the requirements with Python2 rather than Python3. By installing the requirements with Python3, I no longer received a syntax error.

Comment: Btw, why do you pack the boto3? It is default package and has been installed already on the lambda.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your lambda function doesn't have the IAM role for S3. You may specify the Access key and Secret key to the resource directly,

```
resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id='AKIAIO5FODNN7E******', # not real
    aws_secret_access_key='ABCDEF+c2L7yXeGvUyrPgYsDnWRRC1AYE******' # not real
)
```

or have to give the right permission to the lambda function.