# Invalid syntax error using AWS' boto3 for the service 's3' (boto3/s3/inject.py:233)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having some trouble interacting with AWS' s3 client. I'm simply trying to set up the client but I'm getting a weird error message.

### Steps I'm trying to execute

#### Step 1: importing packages

```
from pkg_dir.config import *
from pkg_dir.src.utils import *
import boto3
```

#### Step 2: reading credentials to connect to AWS

```
creds = read_yaml(creds_file_path)
```

This step results in saving the following dict in the `creds` variable:

```
{
    'aws': {
        'aws_access_key_id': 'XXX',
        'aws_secret_access_key': 'YYY'
    }
}
```

#### Step 3: creating session for AWS

```
dev = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=creds['aws']['aws_access_key_id'],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['aws']['aws_secret_access_key'],
)
```

#### Step 4: setting up client for S3

```
s3 = dev.client('s3')
```

When I run this line, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3398 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  Input In [6] in <cell line: 1>
    dev.client('s3')
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py:299 in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py:948 in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:112 in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:168 in _create_client_class
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:412 in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:256 in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:239 in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/utils.py:65 in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/utils.py:56 in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File ~/Documents/ReposRob_RobPer/personal/kaggle/kgl_space_titanic/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py:233
    return self.meta.client.upload_file(,
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

One strange thing is that I don't get the same error when I run these other lines of code:

```
dev.client('ec2')
```

```
dev.client('machinelearning')
```

It seems that the problem only happens with the `s3` service

### Configuration

#### Requirements installed:

Command:

```
pip3 freeze
```

Result:

```
anyio==3.6.1
appnope==0.1.3
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asttokens==2.0.5
attrs==21.4.0
awscli==1.25.10
Babel==2.10.1
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bleach==5.0.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.24.10
botocore==1.27.10
certifi==2022.5.18.1
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
colorama==0.4.4
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.0
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
executing==0.8.3
fastjsonschema==2.15.3
fonttools==4.33.3
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.11.4
ipykernel==6.13.0
ipython==8.4.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
jmespath==1.0.0
json5==0.9.8
jsonschema==4.6.0
jupyter-client==7.3.1
jupyter-core==4.10.0
jupyter-server==1.17.0
jupyterlab==3.1.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-server==2.14.0
kaggle==1.5.12
kiwisolver==1.4.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib==3.5.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
nbclassic==0.3.7
nbclient==0.6.4
nbconvert==6.5.0
nbformat==5.4.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.5
notebook==6.4.11
notebook-shim==0.1.0
numpy==1.22.4
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.2
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.1.1
prometheus-client==0.14.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.29
protobuf==4.21.1
psutil==5.9.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.12.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.18.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-slugify==6.1.2
pytz==2022.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
pyzmq==23.1.0
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.7.2
s3transfer==0.6.0
scipy==1.8.1
seaborn==0.11.2
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
stack-data==0.2.0
terminado==0.15.0
text-unidecode==1.3
tinycss2==1.1.1
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.64.0
traitlets==5.2.2.post1
Unidecode==1.3.4
urllib3==1.26.9
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.3.2
zipp==3.8.0
```

#### Python version

Command:

```
python -V
```

Result:

```
Python 3.9.1
```

#### Additional notes

- I'm using `virtualenv` to handle packages

### Consulted references

- I've been trying to find the solution to this problem in other posts, but I've been unsuccessful. These are some of the references I've checked that haven't helped me solve the problem:

  - [fails downloading file from s3 using python3.7.0](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1822)
  - [Can't create s3 resource/client in boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207679/cant-create-s3-resource-client-in-boto3)
  - [SyntaxError when calling boto3.clilent('s3')](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1399)
  - [Does boto3 v1.9.244 support creating an 's3' resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292741/does-boto3-v1-9-244-support-creating-an-s3-resource)
  - [AWS Boto3 Syntax errors in policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880657/aws-boto3-syntax-errors-in-policy)
- Most of these posts solve the problem dealing with a python package called `futures`. However, I don't even have that one installed.

Hope you're able to help me :)

Comment: "It seems that the problem only happens with the ec2 service", 
Should it not say s3?

Comment: Thanks @ErikAsplund, you were totally right. I just edited that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the version of `boto3` you have installed has somehow picked up an extra comma at the end of a line.

The [line in question](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/s3/inject.py#L233) doesn't have a comma at the end of it. Also, according to the Git history, this line hasn't changed since 2015.

If I found myself in this situation, I would try uninstalling and reinstalling `boto3`. I'm not sure it's worth manually editing the file in question and deleting the comma, as there could be other problems with this file, or with other files within `boto3`.

Comment: Hey @Luke Woodward. I did just as you mentioned and it solved my problem. Thanks a lot for suggesting it.